# Place Object received from server into my own class

Tags: javascript, class, object, ionic-framework

I have the following class setup.

**Deviceinfo  class**

```
export class DeviceInfo {
_id: string; // MongoDb automatically adds this so this is just a placeholder
// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
id: string;
// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
name: String;
photo: string;
// Class contains all information on specific devices such as their ID, CurrentOwner and their ImageUrl
constructor(id2: string, devOwner: string, ph: string) {// Constructor to create an instance of the class
    this.id = id2;
    this.name = devOwner;
    this.photo = ph;

}
}
```

And i sent a request to a server to get info on devices stored in this info. 
I use the following method to get values from the server

**Code from deviceinfo.ts class**

```
   this.getdeviceinfo().then(res => {


    })
    .catch(err => {});
```

The method looks like this

**GetDeviceinfo method**

```
   async getdeviceinfo() {
  return await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let timesDone = 0;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-var-keyword
    const viewDevicesLink = '/devices/info/view'; // parameter: email
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // xhr.open('POST', this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS + '/user/devices/view/', true);
    xhr.open('POST', this.AUTH_SERVER_ADDRESS  + viewDevicesLink, true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/JSON;charset=UTF-8');
    const us = new DeviceInfo('1', '', '');


    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(us));

    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', processRequest, false);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = processRequest;

    function processRequest(e) {
        // tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            // tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
            if (timesDone == 0) {
                // tslint:disable-next-line: prefer-const
                const response  = xhr.response;
                timesDone++;
                alert(JSON.parse(response));
                resolve(JSON.parse(response));

            }
        // tslint:disable-next-line: triple-equals
        } else if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert('server error: ' + xhr.status + ', response is: ' + xhr.responseText);
            timesDone++;
            return null;
        }

    }

  });
```

}

The method gets the information and when i stringify the response from the server i in the classinfo.ts class i get the following.

```
{"_id":"5d7548aa1c9d4400009d0c66","id":"1","name":"Mr Meowgi's Old Person Collar","photo":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j and then some jiberish
```

Which is great but how do i get this response(the object it returns) into a instance of the Deviceinfo class? 
I used

```
var device = res.
```

but that is the simply of type unknown. How would i get it to be of type deviceInfo? Thanks for the help

Comment: I use [`typestack/class-transformer`](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library for this issue.

Comment: Seeing as you know the structure of this object, you could loop through it and build the js obj manually. If you didn't know, you could use a recursive function to traverse it.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz could you possibly provide me with an example of how to do this?

Comment: @JDunken how would i do this recursively? Thx for the response

Comment: You know the structure of `Deviceinfo` so you don't need recursion. You just need to loop through the returned object, assign the properties you want from it to variables and then use the constructor of the `Deviceinfo` class you have already created.

Answer (score 0):

When I return data from my server I like to put the return data in a object

```
const data = {
       serverResponse: xhr.response,
       status: 200,
       success: true     
}
```

then I return the object as is.....

```
return res.send({data:data})
```

On the front end...

```
fetch("http://localhost:4000/api/yourEndPoint")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(myResponse => {
  let dataContainer = response.data;
  let returnedSuccessMessage = dataContainer.success; // output true
})
.catch(err => {//  do something with err})
```